# juju bootstrap on private openstrack cloud failed

Tags: ssh, juju, openstack

I want to deploy juju over my Openstack cloud. The issue I am facing is that the juju bootstrap is giving a time out error every time. The floating IP that gets assigned to the instance is not able to ssh. It either says no route to host found, connection refused or permission denied.
My environments.ymal file is:
openstack:
        type: openstack

```
    # use-floating-ip specifies whether a floating IP address is
    # required to give the nodes a public IP address. Some
    # installations assign public IP addresses by default without
    # requiring a floating IP address.
    #
    use-floating-ip: true

    # use-default-secgroup specifies whether new machine instances
    # should have the "default" Openstack security group assigned.
    #
    use-default-secgroup: true

    # network specifies the network label or uuid to bring machines up
    # on, in the case where multiple networks exist. It may be omitted
    # otherwise.
    #
    # network: 3db0da69-c062-48a3-b441-98308161d779

    # agent-metadata-url specifies the location of the Juju tools and
    # metadata. It defaults to the global public tools metadata
    # location https://streams.canonical.com/tools.
    # 'http://controller:8080/v1/AUTH_%(tenant_id)s/simplestreams/tools/' 
    agent-metadata-url: 'http://controller:8080/v1/AUTH_%(tenant_id)s/simplestreams/tools/'

    # image-metadata-url specifies the location of Ubuntu cloud image
    # metadata. It defaults to the global public image metadata
    # location https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases.
    #'http://controller:8080/v1/AUTH_%(tenant_id)s/simplestreams/images/'
    image-metadata-url: 'http://controller:8080/v1/AUTH_%(tenant_id)s/simplestreams/images/'

    # image-stream chooses a simplestreams stream from which to select
    # OS images, for example daily or released images (or any other stream
    # available on simplestreams).
    #
    image-stream: "released"

    # agent-stream chooses a simplestreams stream from which to select tools,
    # for example released or proposed tools (or any other stream available
    # on simplestreams).
    #
    agent-stream: "released"

    # auth-url defaults to the value of the environment variable
    # OS_AUTH_URL, but can be specified here.
    #
    auth-url: http://controller:5000/v2.0

    # tenant-name holds the openstack tenant name. It defaults to the
    # environment variable OS_TENANT_NAME.
    #
    tenant-name: demo

    # region holds the openstack region. It defaults to the
    # environment variable OS_REGION_NAME.
    #
    region: regionOne

    # The auth-mode, username and password attributes are used for
    # userpass authentication (the default).
    #
    # auth-mode holds the authentication mode. For user-password
    # authentication, auth-mode should be "userpass" and username and
    # password should be set appropriately; they default to the
    # environment variables OS_USERNAME and OS_PASSWORD respectively.
    #
    auth-mode: userpass
    username: demo
    password: ***********

    # For key-pair authentication, auth-mode should be "keypair" and
    # access-key and secret-key should be set appropriately; they
    # default to the environment variables OS_ACCESS_KEY and
    # OS_SECRET_KEY respectively.
    #
    # auth-mode: keypair
    # access-key: <secret>
    # secret-key: <secret>

    # Whether or not to refresh the list of available updates for an
    # OS. The default option of true is recommended for use in
    # production systems, but disabling this can speed up local
    # deployments for development or testing.
    #
    enable-os-refresh-update: false

    # Whether or not to perform OS upgrades when machines are
    # provisioned. The default option of true is recommended for use
    # in production systems, but disabling this can speed up local
    # deployments for development or testing.
    #
    enable-os-upgrade: false

# https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-hpcloud.html
```

The output of juju bootstrap --debug is : https://paste.ubuntu.com/24468475/

Comment: can you share juju version installed? you can run the bootstrap command with --debug flag for more verbosity.

Comment: I have added the output with --debug parameter as suggested. Please give some idea where I might be going wrong. In the .jenv file that is generated I see that the ssh public keys are added in the authorized-keys parameter. But when I try to ssh in to the juju instance using the private key I get connection refused. Also on the dashboard I see that there is no key pair associated with the juju instance that spawns up. It might be a very trivial thing but I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: The machine from where you're running the $ juju bootstrap command, does that has access to "172.16.50.0" network?

Comment: I ran a ping command for the ip 172.16.50.0 it says destination host unreachable.

Comment: The gateway IP for this network is 172.16.0.1, I have a openstack VM which I can ssh into from the system. But the juju VM's ssh is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about security group in openstack, you should add default security group when you bootstrap the controller.

Comment: i tried this. did not work `juju bootstrap --bootstrap-series=$OS_SERIES \
  --metadata-source=~/simplestreams \
  --model-default network=test \
  --model-default external-network=external \
  --model-default use-floating-ip=true \
  --config use-default-secgroup=true \
 --debug \
  microstack microstack `